# How do I animate fadeIn fadeOut effect in NSTextField when changing its text?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, osx-lion

I am trying to write a category for `NSTextField` which will add a new method `setAnimatedStringValue`. This method is supposed to nicely fade-out the current text, then set the new text and then fade that in.

Below is my implementation:-

```
- (void) setAnimatedStringValue:(NSString *)aString {

    if ([[self stringValue] isEqualToString:aString]) {
        return;
    }

    NSMutableDictionary *dict = Nil;

    NSViewAnimation *fadeOutAnim;
    dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:self, NSViewAnimationTargetKey,
            NSViewAnimationFadeOutEffect, NSViewAnimationEffectKey, nil];
    fadeOutAnim = [[NSViewAnimation alloc] initWithViewAnimations:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                                               dict, nil]];
    [fadeOutAnim setDuration:2];
    [fadeOutAnim setAnimationCurve:NSAnimationEaseOut];
    [fadeOutAnim setAnimationBlockingMode:NSAnimationBlocking];

    NSViewAnimation *fadeInAnim;
    dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:self, NSViewAnimationTargetKey,
            NSViewAnimationFadeInEffect, NSViewAnimationEffectKey, nil];
    fadeInAnim = [[NSViewAnimation alloc] initWithViewAnimations:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                                                   dict, nil]];
    [fadeInAnim setDuration:3];
    [fadeInAnim setAnimationCurve:NSAnimationEaseIn];
    [fadeInAnim setAnimationBlockingMode:NSAnimationBlocking];

    [fadeOutAnim startAnimation];

    [self setStringValue:aString];

    [fadeInAnim startAnimation];
}
```

Needless to say, but the above code does not work at all. The only effect I see is the flickering of a progress bar on the same window. That is possibly because I am blocking the main runloop while trying to "animate" it.

Please suggest what is wrong with the above code.

**Additional note:**

`setAnimatedStringValue` is always invoked by a `NSTimer`, which is added to the main `NSRunLoop`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll take a stab:

I found a couple problems here. First off, this whole thing is set up to be blocking, so it's going to block the main thread for 5 seconds. This will translate to the user as a SPOD/hang.  You probably want this to be non-blocking, but it'll require a little bit of extra machinery to make that happen.

Also, you're using `NSAnimationEaseOut` for the fade out effect, which is effected by a known bug where it causes the animation to run backwards. *(Google for "NSAnimationEaseOut backwards" and you can see that many have hit this problem.)* I used `NSAnimationEaseIn` for both curves for this example.

I got this working for a trivial example with non-blocking animations. I'm not going to say that this is the *ideal* approach (I posted a second answer that arguably better), but it works, and can hopefully serve as a jumping off point for you. Here's the crux of it:

```
@interface NSTextField (AnimatedSetString)

- (void) setAnimatedStringValue:(NSString *)aString;

@end

@interface SOTextFieldAnimationDelegate : NSObject <NSAnimationDelegate>

- (id)initForSettingString: (NSString*)newString onTextField: (NSTextField*)tf;

@end

@implementation NSTextField (AnimatedSetString)

- (void) setAnimatedStringValue:(NSString *)aString
{
    if ([[self stringValue] isEqual: aString])
    {
        return;
    }

    [[[SOTextFieldAnimationDelegate alloc] initForSettingString: aString onTextField: self] autorelease];
}

@end


@implementation SOTextFieldAnimationDelegate
{
    NSString* _newString;
    NSAnimation* _fadeIn;
    NSAnimation* _fadeOut;
    NSTextField* _tf;
}

- (id)initForSettingString: (NSString*)newString onTextField: (NSTextField*)tf
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        _newString = [newString copy];
        _tf = [tf retain];

        [self retain]; // we'll autorelease ourselves when the animations are done.

        _fadeOut = [[NSViewAnimation alloc] initWithViewAnimations: @[ (@{
                                                                        NSViewAnimationTargetKey : tf ,
                                                                        NSViewAnimationEffectKey : NSViewAnimationFadeOutEffect})] ];
        [_fadeOut setDuration:2];
        [_fadeOut setAnimationCurve: NSAnimationEaseIn];
        [_fadeOut setAnimationBlockingMode:NSAnimationNonblocking];
        _fadeOut.delegate = self;

        _fadeIn = [[NSViewAnimation alloc] initWithViewAnimations: @[ (@{
                                                                        NSViewAnimationTargetKey : tf ,
                                                                        NSViewAnimationEffectKey : NSViewAnimationFadeInEffect})] ];
        [_fadeIn setDuration:3];
        [_fadeIn setAnimationCurve:NSAnimationEaseIn];
        [_fadeIn setAnimationBlockingMode:NSAnimationNonblocking];

        [_fadeOut startAnimation];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [_newString release];
    [_tf release];
    [_fadeOut release];
    [_fadeIn release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)animationDidEnd:(NSAnimation*)animation
{
    if (_fadeOut == animation)
    {
        _fadeOut.delegate = nil;
        [_fadeOut release];
        _fadeOut = nil;

        _tf.hidden = YES;
        [_tf setStringValue: _newString];

        _fadeIn.delegate = self;
        [_fadeIn startAnimation];
    }
    else
    {
        _fadeIn.delegate = nil;
        [_fadeIn release];
        _fadeIn = nil;

        [self autorelease];
    }
}

@end
```

It would be really nice if there were block-based API for this... it'd save having to implement this delegate object.

I put the whole project up on [GitHub](https://github.com/ipmcc/SOExamples/tree/master/animation/AnimTextField).

Comment: Wow... I never expected that animation curves can modify the animated property. I expected them to only effect the rate of change of property w.r.t. time. So, for `NSAnimationEaseOut`, the rate of decrease in Alpha value would decrease as animation progresses.

Comment: Yeah, it was puzzling to me as well, and seems to run against the documentation, but that's what I observed. I'm not sure exactly what is going on there.

Comment: Googling for "NSAnimationEaseOut backwards" yields many who have run into this problem, so the answer seems to be "known bug".

Answer (score 9):

I was poking around a bit after posting the previous answer.  I'm leaving that answer because it corresponds closely to the code you posted, and uses `NSViewAnimation`.  I did, however, come up with a considerably more concise, albeit slightly harder to read (owing to block parameter indentation) version that uses `NSAnimationContext` instead. Here 'tis:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface NSTextField (AnimatedSetString)

- (void) setAnimatedStringValue:(NSString *)aString;

@end

@implementation NSTextField (AnimatedSetString)

- (void) setAnimatedStringValue:(NSString *)aString
{
    if ([[self stringValue] isEqual: aString])
    {
        return;
    }

    [NSAnimationContext runAnimationGroup:^(NSAnimationContext *context) {
        [context setDuration: 1.0];
        [context setTimingFunction: [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut]];
        [self.animator setAlphaValue: 0.0];
    }
                        completionHandler:^{
        [self setStringValue: aString];
        [NSAnimationContext runAnimationGroup:^(NSAnimationContext *context) {
            [context setDuration: 1.0];
            [context setTimingFunction: [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn]];
            [self.animator setAlphaValue: 1.0];
        } completionHandler: ^{}];
    }];
}

@end
```

**Note:** To get access to the `CAMediaTimingFunction` class used here for specifying non-default timing functions using this API, you'll need to include `QuartzCore.framework` in your project.

Also on [GitHub](https://github.com/ipmcc/SOExamples/tree/master/animation/AnimTextFieldUsingNSAnimationContext).

Comment: +1 Yesterday evening this exactly how I finally fixed it myself. However, my code was not this much elegant.

Answer (score 8):

For Swift 3, here are two convenient `setText()` and `setAttributedText()` extension methods that fade over from one text to another:

```
import Cocoa

extension NSTextField {
    func setStringValue(_ newValue: String, animated: Bool = true, interval: TimeInterval = 0.7) {
        guard stringValue != newValue else { return }
        if animated {
            animate(change: { self.stringValue = newValue }, interval: interval)
        } else {
            stringValue = newValue
        }
    }

    func setAttributedStringValue(_ newValue: NSAttributedString, animated: Bool = true, interval: TimeInterval = 0.7) {
        guard attributedStringValue != newValue else { return }
        if animated {
            animate(change: { self.attributedStringValue = newValue }, interval: interval)
        }
        else {
            attributedStringValue = newValue
        }
    }

    private func animate(change: @escaping () -> Void, interval: TimeInterval) {
        NSAnimationContext.runAnimationGroup({ context in
            context.duration = interval / 2.0
            context.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut)
            animator().alphaValue = 0.0
        }, completionHandler: {
            change()
            NSAnimationContext.runAnimationGroup({ context in
                context.duration = interval / 2.0
                context.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut)
                self.animator().alphaValue = 1.0
            }, completionHandler: {})
        })
    }
}
```

Call them as following:

```
var stringTextField: NSTextField
var attributedStringTextField: NSTextField
...
stringTextField.setStringValue("New Text", animated: true)
...
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "New Attributed Text")
attributedString.addAttribute(...)
attributedStringTextField.setAttributedStringValue(attributedString, animated: true)
```