# How to give Fade In/Fade Out effect in NSTextField in cocoa Application?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, animation

I am working on the `MAC` app in which i want to give `Fade In`/`Fade Out` animation.

I have used `NSTextField` and Want to give this animation on it.

I have searched for it but could not find any solution for this.

So please provide solution for this.

Comment: you can check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14174911/how-do-i-animate-fadein-fadeout-effect-in-nstextfield-when-changing-its-text

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25456080/cocoa-nsview-animation